# Can you recommend a molecular modeling book targeted at polymers or biomolecules that supplies programming examples?

Tags: reference-request

I know one book -

> Molecular Simulation of Fluids Theory, Algorithms, and Object-Orientation; Richard J. Sadus.

This book supplies source code. However, it is not targeted at polymers or biomolecules.

Can you recommend a better book?

Comment: Since there are lots of kinds of molecular modeling - are there particular topics in mind? Molecular dynamics? Quantum chemistry? etc.?

Comment: @GeoffHutchison, Monte Carlo simulation of proteins or polymers.

Comment: @user366312 Monte Carlo simulation for what purpose? For electronic structure? For dynamics?

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP returns and addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.